# ¿Cómo pasar una prop de un hijo a otro? (React Hooks)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-hooks, react-router-dom

Necesito pasar una prop (es un id único) de un componente hijo a otro, pero no consigo hacerlo.

El funcionamiento es simple: Homepage es el padre y tiene dos hijos directos: Gallery y Detail. Gallery mediante un map imprime sus hijos Cards, los cuales tienen un id único. Necesito que al clicar en el botón de una card, ese id único lo pueda recibir Detail.

He intentado gestionarlo a través de handleClick pero como por ahí ya gestiono un estado, no sé si es posible gestionarlo también desde ahí o hay otros métodos.

Este es el código:

```
interface DetailProps {

}

const Detail: React.FC<DetailProps> = props => {
    return (
        <div >
            <span className="tituloJuego">
                DENTRO DE DETAIL
            </span>

        </div>
    );
}

interface CardProps {
    id: number;
    image: string;
    title: string;
    price: string;
    onClick: (result: string) => void;
}

const Card: React.FC<CardProps> = props => {
    return (
        <div className="card" >
            <img className="image"
                src={props.image}
            />

            <div className="card-info">
                <div className="containerTitlePrice">
                    <span className="tituloJuego">
                        {props.title}
                    </span>
                    <br></br>
                    <span className="-USD">
                        {props.price}
                    </span>
                </div>

                <div className="containerButton">
                    <button className="Rectangle" onClick={(event) => props.onClick("detail")}>
                        <span className="Install-Game">
                            BUY NOW
                        </span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}


interface GalleryProps {
    onClick: (result: string) => void;
}

const Gallery: React.FC<GalleryProps> = props => {

    return (
        // Se recorren los datos de json con map y se imprime cada card
        <div className="container">
            {data.map((games, key) => {
                return (
                    <Card
                        id={games.id}
                        image={games.image}
                        title={games.title}
                        price={games.price}
                        onClick={(event) => props.onClick("detail")} />
                );
            })}
        </div>
    )
}

const Homepage: React.FC = () => {
    // Por defecto el estado muestra homepage
    const [currentView, setCurrentView] = React.useState<string>("homepage");
    const handleClick = () => setCurrentView("detail");

    const [currentClickedGame, setCurrentClickedGame] = React.useState<number>(0);

    return (
        <div className="Simplified-homepage">
            {
                currentView === "homepage" ?
                    <div className="store-gallery">
                        <Gallery
                            onClick={handleClick}
                        />
                    </div> :

                    <div className="">
                        <Detail
                        />
                    </div>
            }

        </div>
    );
}

// ========================================

ReactDOM.render(<Homepage />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Para cuando ya debes pasar muchos props es mejor usar contextos

Comment: Si de `Gallery` deriva la informacion de cada `Card` (Detail) se podría llamar al componente `Detail` desde el mismo `Gallery`, se me ocurre un `pop-up/modal` en el onClick de Card.

Comment: al ser dos componentes que se encuentran al mismo nivel, lo ideal seria utilizar el context, es decir que el padre comparta el conexto con ambos hijos. https://react.dev/reference/react/createContext
https://react.dev/reference/react/useContext En el padre deberias crear el conexto y en los hijos acceder mediante el useConext Saludos